# Microsoft Azure cognition service - Face detection fails in landscape (face) mode

Tags: python, image-processing, azure-cognitive-services

I'm using the MS cognition service through it API to analyse images and noticed that when the images are in the landscape mode ('faces are not vertically aligned') it returns an empty result. I'm very puzzled and am wondering whether I'm doing something wrong, or it is how the MS service works. Here is a simple example to reproduce the problem.

**You should have the MS Face subscription key to be able to use the service!**

```
import requests
# If you are using a Jupyter notebook, uncomment the following line.
#%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import patches
from io import BytesIO

# send request to MS, use YOUR subscription key
subscription_key = "982374kwhXXXxxxx"
assert subscription_key

face_api_url ='https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect'
header = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': face_api_url }
headers  = {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscription_key, "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream" }

params = {
    'returnFaceId': 'true',
    'returnFaceLandmarks': 'false',
    'returnFaceAttributes': 'age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair,glasses,' +
    'emotion,hair,makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure,noise'
}

# get a random image and convert to numpy array
image_url = 'https://how-old.net/Images/faces2/main007.jpg'
image = Image.open(BytesIO(requests.get(image_url).content))
image_np = np.array(image)
```

here is the image:

[image]

then run the MS Face recognition analysis:

```
    # save image into a buffer
    buf = io.BytesIO()
    plt.imsave(buf, image_np, format='jpg')


    response = requests.post(face_api_url, params=params, headers=headers, data=buf.getvalue())
    faces = response.json()
    print(faces)
```

With correct output:

```
[{'faceId': '56afb612-f737-44da-8b62-511070527e18',   'faceRectangle': {'top': 209, 'left': 229, 'width': 91, 'height': 91},   'faceAttributes': {'smile': 1.0,    'headPose': {'pitch': 0.0, 'roll':
3.7, 'yaw': 1.2},    'gender': 'female',    'age': 29.0,    'facialHair': {'moustache': 0.0, 'beard': 0.0, 'sideburns': 0.0},    'glasses': 'NoGlasses',    'emotion': {'anger': 0.0,
    'contempt': 0.0,
    'disgust': 0.0,
    'fear': 0.0,
    'happiness': 1.0,
    'neutral': 0.0,
    'sadness': 0.0,
    'surprise': 0.0},    'blur': {'blurLevel': 'low', 'value': 0.02},    'exposure': {'exposureLevel': 'goodExposure', 'value': 0.65},    'noise': {'noiseLevel': 'medium', 'value': 0.31},    'makeup': {'eyeMakeup': True, 'lipMakeup': True},    'accessories': [],    'occlusion': {'foreheadOccluded': False,
    'eyeOccluded': False,
    'mouthOccluded': False},    'hair': {'bald': 0.05,
    'invisible': False,
    'hairColor': [{'color': 'brown', 'confidence': 1.0},
     {'color': 'blond', 'confidence': 0.48},
     {'color': 'black', 'confidence': 0.35},
     {'color': 'red', 'confidence': 0.27},
     {'color': 'gray', 'confidence': 0.19},
     {'color': 'other', 'confidence': 0.03}]}}},  {'faceId': 'dfb667ba-3fe7-42fc-b9ba-06a86619e94d',   'faceRectangle': {'top': 110, 'left': 125, 'width': 76, 'height': 76},   'faceAttributes': {'smile': 1.0,    'headPose': {'pitch': 0.0, 'roll': 2.3, 'yaw': 2.2}, 'gender': 'male',    'age': 32.0,    'facialHair': {'moustache': 0.4, 'beard': 0.4, 'sideburns': 0.1},    'glasses': 'NoGlasses',    'emotion': {'anger': 0.0,
    'contempt': 0.0,
    'disgust': 0.0,
    'fear': 0.0,
    'happiness': 1.0,
    'neutral': 0.0,
    'sadness': 0.0,
    'surprise': 0.0},    'blur': {'blurLevel': 'low', 'value': 0.02},    'exposure': {'exposureLevel': 'goodExposure', 'value': 0.72},    'noise': {'noiseLevel': 'low', 'value': 0.01},    'makeup': {'eyeMakeup': False, 'lipMakeup': True},    'accessories': [],    'occlusion': {'foreheadOccluded': False,
    'eyeOccluded': False,
    'mouthOccluded': False},    'hair': {'bald': 0.02,
    'invisible': False,
    'hairColor': [{'color': 'brown', 'confidence': 1.0},
     {'color': 'blond', 'confidence': 0.92},
     {'color': 'red', 'confidence': 0.66},
     {'color': 'gray', 'confidence': 0.25},
     {'color': 'other', 'confidence': 0.02},
     {'color': 'black', 'confidence': 0.01}]}}}]
```

However, if I swap the axes (transpose the image), I get a zero result ('empty')

```
# save image into a buffer
buf = io.BytesIO()
plt.imsave(buf, np.swapaxes(image_np, 0,1), format='jpg')
```

[image]

```
response = requests.post(face_api_url, params=params, headers=headers, data=buf.getvalue())
faces = response.json()
print(faces)
```

The result will be an empty list:

```
[]
```

I am wondering whether has anyone come accross this problem and what could be done to have the MS service working properly, regardless of the rotation or position of an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually states [here](https://westus2.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236/) that there are cases that faces may not be detected, including wrong image orientation.

> Face detector prefer frontal and near-frontal faces. There are cases
>   that faces may not be detected, e.g. exceptionally large face angles
>   (head-pose) or being occluded, or wrong image orientation.

You can handle that on your side instead, by detecting the direction of the faces, rotate the picture according to that, and then send it!

Comment: thanks. I'm wondering how you can find the direction of a face without using the MSF service?

Comment: If you can't find a solution to do that for the current time, a workaround would be to make a condition that checks if the result is empty and rotate the image, until it returns something, that would do it until you find an optimal solution.